# Need Help with Preference table database design

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently developing a web application using MYSQL database InnoDB format and need some help with my preference database desgin.

Basically I need to have a preference table to determine the user car brand preference.

BMW           0 or 1
TOYOTA        0 or 1
HONDA         0 or 1
MERCEDES      0 or 1
HOLDEN        0 or 1
FORD          0 or 1                  (0 means dislike and 1 means like)

I used to store all the responses in one table but is hard to maintain when I add new car brand . So I need to make it dynamic so I don't have to modify the database column when i add more car brands.

So Each User in my system have their own user's car preference profile.

So my new design its to have a user table, preference table and a UserPreference table

```
UserPreference table

providerId
preferenceId
response
```

My Question is How can I populate the User preference profile rows in the database (default all to 0) once a new user sign up  ?

Or should I make my UserPreference table like below so I don't have to populate  the user preference profile rows? And only create a row in the User Preference table when a user like a car brand.

Which is a better approach?

```
UserPreference table

    providerId
    preferenceId
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second approach is the best option, Only add the preferences that people have explicitly chosen.  That way you can assume when working with the data that everything is 0 unless a preference exists in the table to show otherwise.